# Firefox wrongly trims trailing white space when editing

Tags: javascript, editing, trailing-whitespace

OS: Linux Mint 18.3, Firefox 72.

I've explored this phenomenon and I find it exists only in FF, not in Chrome (for example).

This problem applies, in general, to elements (perhaps `DIV` or `TD`) when their [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) [contentEditable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable) has been set to `true`.

You can see the problem for yourself if you go [here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/praveenpuglia/8ee8e5d7cd1f08a88ca3/raw/78f08b89311895de0d939310e3e533eded4b965a/Rich%2520Text%2520Editor.html), get that HTML + JS and run it in your browsers.

The specific problem, when you load that file, can be seen if you put the cursor after "ipsum" and then press Ctrl-Backspace, to delete the word "ipsum". The result seems OK: when you see the cursor blinking after that, it appears that there is a trailing space after "Lorem". But when I then type some letter after that it gets stuck to "Lorem"... e.g. I type "m" and I see "Loremm".

This is not how it works with that same HTML file in Chrome: there, when I type "m", I see "Lorem m".

Even more strangely, when I type more words, in Firefox, after "Lorem ipsum" ... and then use Ctrl-Backspace and start typing, the problem does not occur: trailing white space is preserved properly.

There is another thing I've observed in FF: if, instead of going Ctrl-Backspace, I repeatedly go Backspace, i.e. letter-by-letter, until I've deleted "ipsum", leaving the trailing space. And if I then start typing ... trailing white space is preserved.

I have gone to the extent of writing a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to see what's happening here and whether there's a possible workaround. The problem is that the FF browser in fact does this trimming before the `MutationObserver` fires any event.

There is a possible workaround which I'm working on, which is to trap the key event, and if it is "Ctrl + Backspace" to do `event.preventDefault()`.  This does indeed stop the word-deletion occurring. I'd then have to implement a substitute solution, involving perhaps deleting letter-by-letter until I find white space.

This looks like a bug to me.

Here's a *possible* clue to what this *might* be about: when I first trap this event (i.e. on Ctrl-Backspace) and examine the `event.target`, I find that the `innerHTML` is correct, i.e. has a trailing space, but that the `innerText` is incorrect, i.e. the trailing space has been trimmed. I have done a bit of reading about this, and it appears that `innerText` is, so they say, primarily concerned with "how some text is presented on the page".